# JavaScript call() and apply() Method and variable assignment

Tags: javascript, call, apply, variable-assignment

I am currently learning JavaScript using a book. An example explains the dual purpose of functions.

```
function Person(name) {
  if (this instanceof Person) {
    this.name = name
  } else {
    throw new Error("Nutze new")
  }
}
let aPerson = new Person("Astrid"); 
// let aPerson = Person("Astrid"); // throws an error
let notAPerson = Person.apply(aPerson, ["Elmar"]);
let notAPerson2 = Person.call(aPerson, "Peter");
console.log(aPerson); //  Object { name: "Peter" }
console.log(notAPerson); //  undefined
console.log(notAPerson2); //  undefined
```

I understand, that I can set a `contex` with the `apply()` or the `call()` method. 
But I do not understand, why the variables `notAPerson` and `notAPerson2` are undefined?

It would be great if someone could explain this to me.

Comment: Because your constructor function doesn't `return` a value. It just modifies the `this` object.

Comment: I'd like to mark this as a typo but I'm not sure I should. Really, you are asking why a `function doesNotReturnAnything() { console.log("this is the entire body") }` when invoked does not produce a value.

Comment: Many Thanks. Now it is clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `new` keyword changes how your function executes. When used without `new`, it does exactly what it says it does in the function body. But when you call the function with `new`, it works kind of like this:

```
function Person(name) {
  var this = {}
  if (this instanceof Person) {
    this.name = name
  } else {
    throw new Error("Nutze new")
  }
  return this
}
```

So when you call the function with `new`, `this` is a brand new object, which gets returned automatically. When you call the function later without `new`, `this` is the `aPerson` object you created previously, because you're explicitly setting the context using `call` and `apply`. Also, when you don't use `new`, the function doesn't return anything, it only assigns to `this`, which is why `notAPerson` and `notAPerson2` remain undefined.

Comment: I'm glad I could clear things up for you. Please select this answer as 'correct' if you feel that it answers your question.